# Why do I have an error in my js? My error " Unused default export "

Tags: javascript, export, default

```
export default function myEmailAddress(myEmail) {

return myEmail;

}

let myResult = myEmailAddress("email.com");
console.log(myResult)
```

Comment: Are you importing `myEmailAddress` anywhere?

Comment: @Andy No I did not, could you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: If you're not importing it anywhere that's why you get the warning. Do you _want_ to import it into another module? At the moment, you're only logging the email address in that module, so there's no reason to export it.

Comment: @Andy I would like to know how it is possible to import to another module if it is easy for you to tell me. Thank you very much for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

the export function is used whenever we want to use this function in another module without writing it again, if it is the only module this function is used, no need for exporting it,
to understand more about exports and default exports and when to use them check this article:https://learnjsx.com/category/2/posts/es6-moduleExports

Comment: Thank you very much for the article and for your explanation. Thank you for your time.